# Adding meshes to URDF using HTTPS URLs

Tags: ros, ros2, urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to figure out if I can add meshes to a URDF using HTTPS URLs instead of using package:// or file://. I wasn't able to find any references about it online, or even any info stating it's not possible.

Is it possible to add meshes this way? I'm using ROS 2 Humble.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/413934/adding-meshes-to-urdf-using-https-urls/) by [adityakamath](https://answers.ros.org/users/28154/adityakamath/) on ROS Answers with karma: 30 on 2023-03-31

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Tried it now and yes, it is possible. However, it depends on whether the visualization tool can parse these web URLs or not. I tried it with Rviz and Foxglove and it works.

---

Originally posted by [adityakamath](https://answers.ros.org/users/28154/adityakamath/) with karma: 30 on 2023-04-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0